# Can I combine these two SQL queries into single query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can I combine these two SQL queries into single query?

query1

```
ALTER TABLE tableA
ADD datam INTEGER;
```

query2

```
UPDATE tableA SET datam = DateDiff("m",[call_date],#12/1/2009#);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no. the first one is not actually a 'query'. it is a statement of [Data Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)

Comment: Agreed but note that this sloppy usage of 'query' is endemic in the Access documentation, particularly 'update query' to mean an UPDATE DML statement and 'delete query' for DELETE DML statement (plus 'action query' collectively!) Also note that you persist the SQL in the Access Database Engine, the resulting object will appear in the 'Queries' tab in the UI.

Comment: This is Access's terminology. You don't have to like it, but it's the way the objects are presented in the UI for ease of understanding by people who are not SQL-heads. You may not agree with MS's decision (made in the early 90s, before SQL 92 was even out) to use terminology in this way, but it is not going to help Access users to have you (or anyone else) quibbling about it at every opportunity. People will just tune you out as the distinction you ask people to make has little utility to them.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: you attacking me or the six (and counting) other people who up-voted this 'quibbling' answer plus the OP who chose it as the answer? ;) Read back what I wrote and you may see that I was coming to the OP's defence.

Comment: Who is attacking? You use the word "endemic" which has a negative connotation, so you clearly don't consider it a good usage.

Comment: The reason the two can't be combined into one statement is not because the first one is a DML statement but because Access/Jet/ACE cannot process multiple SQL statements separated by the ; delimiter. While the answer doesn't explicitly claim that the reason for the NO answer is because it's DML, it's implied, and that's an incorrect explanation. Really it's more a terminological quibble that has nothing to do with the actual answer to the question.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "has nothing to do with the actual answer to the question" -- that's the weird thing about Q&A sites such as stackoverflow: the most ignorant (a pejorative term you favour) person gets to choose the answer i.e. the one who felt the need to ask it. If the OP had known that a DDL statement is not a query then they would have asked a sensible question and got a (more) sensible answer. Who is to blame for this state of affairs? Not the OP, IMO, but the Access Team's historical and continued sloppy usage of the term 'query'.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a help `PROCEDURE` to add the calculated default e.g. ([ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) Access Database Engine SQL syntax):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTableAThing
(
 arg_my_key_column CHAR(10), 
 arg_call_date DATETIME
)
AS 
INSERT INTO tableA (my_key_column, call_date, datam)
SELECT arg_my_key_column, arg_call_date, DATEDIFF('m', [arg_call_date], #2009-12-01 00:00:00#)
  FROM MyOneRowAuxilliaryTable;
```

You could also create a helper functions for `UPDATE` perhaps again to maintain the default.

You could then remove `INSERT`/`UPDATE` privileges from the table to force all applications and users to go via your helper procs to ensure the default is correctly applied.

Comment: In SQL 92 mode, Access will excecute @onedaywhen's SQL. He should have noted the requirement for SQL 92 mode in his posting, but in my experience, he's not one who posts SQL that won't run in Access.

Comment: @gbn "not SQL" -- of course it's SQL: Access Database Engine ANSI-92 Query Mode SQL DDL but its still SQL.

Comment: ah, I've not worked with Access like this. And did not know about PROCEDUREs in Access either.

Comment: It's not the kind of sproc you're accustomed to -- there's no procedural code allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a macro that runs the queries? See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/runsql-macro-action-HA001226285.aspx for more information.

Comment: DoCmd.RunSQL (and the corresponding macro action) are very problematic, in that they default to inconsisten updates. Also, they both generate a prompt, which is usually unwanted, and which is usually turned off, with the result that you can't really tell what data has been updated. Running SQL is much better done with CurrentDB.Execute than by any other method.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Would inconsistent updates really be an issue here? The updated field appears to be an integer with the source value in the same table. Also, you can also turn action prompts off and on inside a macro using SetWarnings. I agree if you want to go with VBA you can get a more robust solution, but I think macros have their place too.

Comment: I think macros have NO PLACE in a serious Access application, except in newer versions of Access where there is error trapping and full logic flow. As to inconsistent updates, the problem is you can't tell what got updated and what didn't, which is why they are so dangerous. Basically, it corrupts your data, since you have no idea of what state it's in after the inconsistent updates.